# Do I need to create a web page/object for each instance of an OpenGraph object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

**Question :** Do I have to create a web page for each instance of "object" against the Facebook Open Graph?

**Info :**

I've created an action `earn` against an object `badge` on the open graph protocol.

I've created a php page with the following content and hosted on heroku:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# myapp: 
                  http://ogp.me/ns/apps/myapp#">
  <title>CarViva</title>
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="myappid" /> 
  <meta property="og:type" content="myapp:badge" /> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="Badge" /> 
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
  <meta property="og:description" content="You've earned a badge!'" /> 
  <meta property="og:url" content="<myurl>/badge.php">
</head>
```

And from my iOS app I'm doing this to invoke the earning of a badge:

```
NSLog(@"Building badge object...");
NSDictionary * theBadge = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Super Awesome badge", @"name", 
                           [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/badge.php",kBackEndServer], @"link",  
                           nil];

[params setValue:[theBadge objectForKey:@"link"] forKey:@"badge"];
// somehow set the badge title (and description, image) here?

[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/myapp:earn" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
NSLog(@"Graph request posted, awaiting response");
```

This works fine, I can see the event showing up in my news feed like so :

[image]

I'm a little confused over the meaning of "object" in regards to the open graph.

`badge` itself would be the object, but I'll have various different kinds, such as "Super awesome badge", "Noob badge", "Pro badge" etc. How can I post an action for an individual one of these?

**Question (slightly more detailed) :** Do I need to create a web page for each individual instance of my facebook OG object OR do I need to create an OG object for each instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question : Do I have to create a web page for each instance of "object" against the Facebook Open Graph?

Of course you do, because that’s what Open Graph objects **are**: URLs that contain data for that specific object instance.